# Distribution algorithm according to weighted parameters (with a min-max constraint)

Tags: algorithm, distribution

I'm trying to solve the following problem related to distribution-

I have a list L of items (I1, I2,....In) sorted in order of importance, I1 being the most important. Each item has multiple tags assigned to it and the combination of these tags can be different on each item, so I1 may have tags T1 and T2, I2 can have tags t2, t3 and t4, and I3 can have tag T1, and so on.

Now, I have to make batches from this list L, with a distribution of items (according to the tags) subject to the following constraints-

1. Each batch has a fixed size B
2. Each tag has a range of items in the batch distribution, ranging from a minimum to maximum. So, B should contain minimum x1 items with tag t1, x2 items with tag t2, and maximum y1 items of t1, y2 items of t2 and so on.
3. We start picking items from the top of L and keep filling the batch until we reach the final distribution that satisfies the constraints. If, say, L has 300 items, and we have to make a batch size of 50, we can go until any number of items in the list and pick the items to make the desired distribution.
4. Remember that if an item is picked from the list, count of all the tags assigned to it goes up by 1.

I was thinking of a solution where in first, I make lists of items corresponding to each specific tag. I pick the minimum desired items for a particular tag from its list. So, I'd pick x1 items with tag t1 from the list of items with tags t1, irrespective of whether the items contain any other tag. This way I'd ensure that the 'minimum' criteria of all the tags are satisfied.  But for the max part, each tag will most definitely go overboard. How do I recursively keep replacing items from the batch with the remaining items in L to make the final desired distribution?

Any other solution would be great. Or any existing algorithm that can get me in the right direction to approach this problem.

I know the question is a bit too wordy, and probably a bit confusing, but I'v tried to explain it as well as I can, and of course, the problem might be a lot interesting I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is an NP-hard problem.  For example, you could reduce graph coloring to it like this.  Each vertex corresponds to an element in your list L, each batch corresponds to a color, and each edge corresponds to a tag which is present only on the two incident vertices.  If you set your constraints so that each batch can only have at most one of each tag, this is equivalent to assigning a color to each vertex in such a way that no two adjacent vertices have the same color.

In situations like this, you basically have two choices:

1. Come up with a reasonable-seeming heuristic that is tuned to the kind of inputs that you think you are going to be encountering.
2. Turn the problem into an integer programming problem and use an available solver, for example lpsolve http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/

Comment: Thanks @mrip..I think this approach of graph coloring might just work, but don't really know how to come up with a reasonable-seeming heuristic. A bit confused. Can you share an example or analogy that can help me do this?

Comment: Graph coloring isn't really an approach, but more of an indication of the fact that this can be a really hard problem to solve for general inputs.  I would not recommend trying to turn this into a graph coloring problem.  To come up with a good heuristic, you have to look at what other kinds of assumptions you can make about your input.